# User interface visualization for passenger-status

Tags: passenger

```
rvmsudo passenger-status --show=requests
```

Is there any User interface visualization for passenger-status, so that we know the current status of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Phusion Passenger author here. No. A web administration interface is planned for the future, but is not available yet.

Comment: Thanks @hongli. I see a lot of client connections in passenger which are waiting for more than 10 mins and the client fails with a Net::ReadTimeout error and has a keep_alive timeout of 3 mins. Its not clear why the passenger instance is not able to serve those requests.

Comment: Probably because your existing app processes are stuck. Try the tips at http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/09/21/the-right-way-to-deal-with-frozen-processes-on-unix/